# Throwing IOException when I try to close the BluetoothSocket

Tags: android

I have a problem with the bluetooth socket, I'm getting an `IOException` telling me: `Socket Closed`

The exception occurs here:

```
} catch (IOException e) {
        try {
          inputStream.close(); 
          socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
             Log.e("CLOSE: ", e.getMessage());
        } 
        Log.e("IO FROM RUN: ", e.getMessage());
}
```

The relevant codesnippet:

```
class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    /**
     * Tag that will appear in the log.
     */
    private final String ACCEPT_TAG = AcceptThread.class.getName();

    /**
     * The bluetooth server socket.
     */
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                    "Bluetooth Service", UUID.fromString(defaultUUID));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        while (true) {
            try {
                Log.i(ACCEPT_TAG, "Listening for a connection...");

                socket = mServerSocket.accept();
                Log.i(ACCEPT_TAG, "Connected to "
                        + socket.getRemoteDevice().getName());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {

                ReadInputThread inputThread = new ReadInputThread(socket); 
                inputThread.start();

            }
        }


    }

    /** Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    class ReadInputThread extends Thread {

        BluetoothSocket socket;
        InputStream inputStream;

        public ReadInputThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tempIs = null;
            try {
                this.socket = socket;
                tempIs = socket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("IO: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            inputStream = tempIs;
        }

        public void run() {

            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN ReadInputThread");
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            while (true) {

                try {
                    bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    if(inputStream.available() < 0) {
                        inputStream.close();
                        socket.close();
                    }

                    Log.i("BYTE COUNT: ", Integer.toString(bytes)); 
                    Log.i("BYTES: ", new String(buffer)); 

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    try {
                        inputStream.close(); 
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.e("CLOSE: ", e.getMessage());
                    } 
                    Log.e("IO FROM RUN: ", e.getMessage());
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Can anybody give me a hint on how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in this code:

```
while (true) {    
try {
                bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                if(inputStream.available() < 0) {
                    inputStream.close();
                    socket.close();
                }

                Log.i("BYTE COUNT: ", Integer.toString(bytes)); 
                Log.i("BYTES: ", new String(buffer)); 

            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close(); 
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.e("CLOSE: ", e.getMessage());
                } 
                Log.e("IO FROM RUN: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

In your while loop, you are first trying to read whats available, and if nothings available, you are closing the socket. The loop then repeats and tries to read from the socket again, but its close, giving you the IOException. 
If you want to exit the loop if there is no data available to read, make sure you add a return or break after socket.close().

Comment: The app reads what the input is, or at least outputs some bytes to LogCat. I tried to put a `break;` after the `socket.close` but the exception still occurs. Thanks anyway.

Comment: the break may just be breaking out of the if statement. 
Label your while loop, e.g. 
myWhileLoop:
while (true){

and then after your socket.close() add a 
break myWhileLoop;